# Apache 2.2.15: Allow from CN require auth from Internet

Tags: apache-2.2, password, httpd.conf, directory

How do I configure httpd.conf for directory /something 
to grant access to everybody from 10.0.0.0/8 withOUT password 
AND to require everybody else coming from whereever to basic authenticate

The goal is simple: Folks from inside my corporate network should be able to access a tiny testsite, whereas folks from outside should only be able to access it, if they know the password. I know, how to achieve either of the two goals, but how to combine them?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you are looking for (especially the `Satisfy any`):

```
AuthName "..."
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

Order deny,allow
Allow from x.x.x.x
Deny from all

Satisfy any
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two separate  configurations in your httpd.conf and use
`RewriteCond  %{REMOTE_HOST}  ^10.0.0.` in passworded location to substitute path for your local users.